# Paragraph within enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate

I'm trying to create an environment for homework assignment problems. Most of these problems consists of itemized questions about an introductory paragraph.

I know I can write a problem environment and put an enumerate environment inside it, but I really want is to be able to write something like this:

```
\begin{problem}
John was born in 1992.

\item How old is John?
\item How old will John be next year?
\end{problem}
```

Ideally, I should also allow \item[1,0] or something similar to specify the question value. The output should be like:

> Question 1. John was born in 1992.
>
> a) How old is John?
>
> b) How old will John be next year?

Is there any enumerating package which supports this behavior? If not, how could I do it manually?

Comment: What should `\item[1,0]` translate to in your output?

Comment: There are some packages devoted to this kind of stuff, namely `exsheets`, `probsoln` or the `exam` class.

Comment: @Werner "a) (1,0 points) How old is John?" for example, although the format is not the biggest issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Johannes_B points out, there are specialized document classes and packages devoted to this.  But if you want something simpler...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{question}
\newenvironment{problem}
{\stepcounter{question}\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\setbox0=\hbox{Question \thequestion.}%
\edef\tmplen{\the\wd0}%
\def\tmp{\makebox[2em][l]{\box0}}%
\item[\tmp]\hspace{\dimexpr\tmplen-2em\relax}}
{\end{enumerate}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{problem}
John was born in 1992.

\item How old is John?
\item How old will John be next year?
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Mary was born in 1995.

\item How old is Mary?
\item How much older than Mary is John?
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thak you very much. I'll take a look at the `exam` class too.